# Bash quote behavior and sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I wrote a short bash script that is supposed to strip the leading tabs/spaces from a string:

```
#!/bin/bash
RGX='s/^[ \t]*//'
SED="sed '$RGX'"
echo "       string" | $SED
```

It works from the command line, but the script gets this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

My guess is that something is wrong with the quotes, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does.  Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
RGX='s/^[ \t]*//'
#SED='$RGX'
echo "       string" | sed "$RGX"
```

This works.

The issue you have is with quotes and spaces.  Double quoted strings are passed as single arguments.

Comment: This is acceptable, however is it possible to lump the sed command and RGX into one string?

Comment: @krs1, in this case, not really.  Since you need `$RGX` to stay as one argument (so that the space in it will not cause it to be interpreted as 2) but you need there to be a space between `sed` and `$RGX` after the pipe to know that you're trying to pipe the string to `sed` and not a program named `sed $RGX`.

Comment: Actually, you could lump them together if you were to execute the line using `eval`, which will expand variables before executing them.  For details, `man bash` and search for " eval " (with spaces in front and back to get to the right spot in the man page under "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS").

Answer (score 5):

Putting commands into variables and getting them back out intact is hard, because quoting doesn't work the way you expect (see [BashFAQ #050, "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).  There are several ways to deal with this:

1) Don't do it unless you really need to.  Seriously, unless you have a good reason to put your command in a variable first, just execute it and don't deal with this messiness.

2) Don't use `eval` unless you really *really* **really** need to.  `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a source of nasty and obscure bugs.  They can be avoided if you understand them well enough and take the necessary precautions to avert them, but this should really be a last resort.

3) If you really must define a command at one point and use it later, either define it as a function or an array.  Here's how to do it with a function:

```
RGX='s/^[ \t]*//'
SEDCMD() { sed "$RGX"; }
echo "       string" | SEDCMD
```

Here's the array version:

```
RGX='s/^[ \t]*//'
SEDCMD=(sed "$RGX")
echo "       string" | "${SEDCMD[@]}"
```

The idiom `"${SEDCMD[@]}"` lets you expand an array, keeping each element a separate word, without any of the problems you're having.

Comment: Good point, quotes are funky in bash scripts.  I'm used to Python quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Add `set -x` to your script.  You'll see that variables within a single-quote mark are not expanded.

Answer (score 1):

+To expand on my comment above:

```
#!/bin/bash
RGX='s/^[[:space:]]+//'
SED="sed -r '$RGX'"
eval "printf \" \tstring\n\" | $SED"
```

Note that this also makes your regex an extended one, for no particular reason.  :-)